# CI - Flexi Auth, $this->flexi_auth->insert_user() shows "Creating default object from empty value" error

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication

I'm starting with Flex Auth in CodeIgniter, and I should missed or misunderstood something.

Any idea why this piece of code is giving an "Creating default object from empty value" error ?

My code :

```
$this->load->library('flexi_auth');

$email = 'nilsbay@xxxx.fr';
$username = 'nils';
$password = 'nilsnils';
$user_data = '';
$group_id = 1;
$activate = TRUE;

$this->flexi_auth->insert_user($email, $username, $password, $user_data, $group_id, $activate);
```

exit();

An other try with FALSE for $user_data :

```
$this->flexi_auth->insert_user($email, $username, $password, FALSE, $group_id, $activate);
```

Gives the same error.

User is added to database.
But there is this error on the page :

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Creating default object from empty value
Filename: models/flexi_auth_lite_model.php
Line Number: 47
```

This is the models/flexi_auth_lite_model.php line 47 :

```
$this->auth->session_name = $this->config->item('sessions','flexi_auth');
```

I did not found something on internet I could understand with "flexi_auth->insert_user" and "Creating default object from empty value".

Thanks for help.
Nils.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue today on a new installation. It turns out that you have to declare $this->auth as a standard class object in your controller before loading the flexi-auth library. This is documented in the demo auth controller (demo-files/application/controllers/auth.php, line 27-29), but not in the installation instructions. The code you need is:

```
// IMPORTANT! This global must be defined BEFORE the flexi auth library is loaded! 
// It is used as a global that is accessible via both models and both libraries, without it, flexi auth will not work.
$this->auth = new stdClass;

// Load 'standard' flexi auth library by default.
$this->load->library('flexi_auth');
```

I am using a custom MY_Controller, so I added the code to the constructor there.